# Zend Skeleton Application not installable anymore?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

got a problem to install zend skeleton.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application /var/www/project


  [Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]
  The contents of https://packagist.org/p/provider-latest%240cbfb40ab72a881d21b70f78286d39cd72e3b0eb8704c13e79dc49624e549973.json do not match its signatu
  re. This could indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$
```

I just installed composer globally

Regaruds
n00n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems packagist is having some issues right now: https://twitter.com/packagist/status/953257504565334016. Give it a try a bit later on and I'm sure it will be fine.